# Writing a new set of data to Plist instead of overwriting it

Tags: iphone, ios, nsmutablearray, plist, save

I'm trying to get a plist to store multiple sets of data, but each time I save (using a button from an ActionSheet), it overwrites the previous set. I want to add multiple 'friends' and their data. I'm not too keen on using Core Data, so I'm wondering how you can do it with a Plist.

Here is the code for the save button:

```
        NSMutableDictionary *friend = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

        NSMutableDictionary *array = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [array setObject:friendName.text forKey:@"Name"];
        [array setObject:friendPhone.text forKey:@"Phone Number"];
        [array setObject:friendEmail.text forKey:@"Email Address"];
        [array setObject:friendChatSN.text forKey:@"Chat Screen Name"];

        [friend setValue:array forKey: @"Friend Data"];


        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

        NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"FriendList.plist"];

        [friend writeToFile:plistPath atomically: TRUE];
```

Instead of overwriting it, how can I modified the code to add a new set of friend data each time I save?

Comment: I miss something or [friend setValue:array forKey: @"Friend Data"]; is your problem? You overwrite your old data setting the array value to the same key each time in the dict...

Comment: I do know that I'm overwriting it. I'm fairly new to iOS and I don't know how to write the code to save a new set of values. If you can be a bit more explicit and modified my code, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here pList behave as an one object. so whenever you try to write something to plist it will be replaced with new data.

Look like you want to save multiple friends record to plist file. Best solution for your question is to use core data or sqlite. But if you want to achieve it using plist, then first get old data from plist and the add new data (friends) to old data then saving to plist should work out.

As per your requirement you should save `NSArray` with multiple `NSDictionary`(friend record) object to pList.

Here is the modified code

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"FriendList.plist"];

    NSMutableArray *friend = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];

    if (nil == friend) {
        friend = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
    }
    else {
        [friend retain];
    }


    NSMutableDictionary *array = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [array setObject:friendName.text forKey:@"Name"];
    [array setObject:friendPhone.text forKey:@"Phone Number"];
    [array setObject:friendEmail.text forKey:@"Email Address"];
    [array setObject:friendChatSN.text forKey:@"Chat Screen Name"];

    [friend addObject:array];
    [array release];



    [friend writeToFile:plistPath atomically: TRUE];
    [friend release];
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of [friend setValue:array forKey: @"Friend Data"]; use a unique key in place of @"Friend Data", like the friend name+surname (at least...), or you'll have each time a single entry in your dictionary.